# TopCoder not able to install java applet Arena? OS X

Tags: java, macos, applet, installation

I registered on the topcoder website and then proceeded to download the applet. What happens is that I am not able to install it , it says

```
  your security settings have blocked an application with an expired or not yet valid       certificate from running
```

I used Safari by the way.

When I click on details I get:

```
      Java Plug-in 10.67.2.01
Using JRE version 1.7.0_67-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /Users/ramapriyasridharan
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
    x:   clear classloader cache
    0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried several methods suggested but got nothing.Any help would be useful.Thank you

Comment: This doesn't really look like a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: You would be better asking this on superuser.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to your specific problem.

Under the security tab in your Java Control Panel > Edit Site List > http://www.topcoder.com > You will be prompted that an unsecure address is dangerous > Proceed anyway. > Program

It has to be that exact web address for it to work because that it was the check runs through.

Answer (score 0):

Try allow Apps downlowded from anywhere to run on your Mac, under General tab of Security & Privacy settings.

Also, open your Java Control Panel from System Settings, and under Security tab, change your Security level to Medium.